# Azure AppendBlob's property AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount is coming as null

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm writing (using .NET) into an azure AppendBlob, and I would like to check before I append anything to it if I have reached the maximun number of blocks that I am allowed to append. [I have read](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/) that limit is 50k so I will use that number. For that I was trying this

```
public async Task ProcessEventsAsync(PartitionContext context, IEnumerable<EventData> messages)
{
    foreach (var message in messages)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_appendBlob.Properties.AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount == _maximumBlockNumberPerBlob)
            {
                CreateBlob(null);
            }
            ProcessMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _log.Error("Failed Processing Message", ex);
        }
    }

    await context.CheckpointAsync();
}
```

But the AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount is coming as null always and the CreateBlob method just creates a new blob (it takes that fishy null argument as I am using the [Timer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) to call it as well). Any ideas why that happens or how could I check it if this is not the way?

Thanks

UPDATE:

The method CreateBlob is as follow:

```
public void CreateBlob(object _)
{
    var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageAccount"));
    var appendBlobReference = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("appendBlobReference");
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var currentDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var container = blobClient.GetContainerReferenc("testContainer");
    container.CreateIfNotExists();
    _appendBlob = container.GetAppendBlobReference($"{folderName}/{appendBlobReference}-{currentDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")}");
    _appendBlob.CreateOrReplace();
}
```

Being _appendBlob a private Field and folderName and appendBlobReference just strings

All these methods are inside a class that implements [IEventProcessor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) as it's for fetching eventsfrom EventHubs, so basically the Task ProcessEvenstAsync is called when there is something new in the stream.

As well, the first time I call the CreateBlob is inside the constructor of that class that implements IEventProcessor using a timer (as I will create a new one every 15 minutes independently of if it's full or no). This bit works

```
_timer = new Timer(CreateBlob, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(int.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("updateBlobNameIntervalInMinutes"))));
```

And the creation

Comment: Please share how you're creating `_appendBlob`. Where are you fetching its properties?

Comment: @GauravMantri I have updated the question, not sure though about where I fetch the properties, as I thought accessing them as I per the line in the if statement would given them to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried to create an append blob using `CloudAppendBlob.CreateOrReplace` and what I noticed is that this doesn't return `AppendBlobCommittedBlockCount` and that's why this property's value remains as `null` (default value).

To populate this value, you would need to fetch blob's properties again. Please add the following line of code after you create the blob and you should see a non-null value in there:

```
        _appendBlob.FetchAttributes();
```

So your code would be:

```
_appendBlob = container.GetAppendBlobReference($"{folderName}/{appendBlobReference}-{currentDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm")}");
    _appendBlob.CreateOrReplace();
    _appendBlob.FetchAttributes();
```